# Can TrueCrypt be configured to dismount certain volumes when you sleep windows?

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt

I know you can have TrueCrypt dismount all volumes on Sleep from the prefs, but I would like to dismount only one particular drive and not the other - is that possible? Perhaps with a powershell script or something??

Comment: Both of the answers below will work, but remember, any documents you have open at the time of the dismount will remain open. you will have to force dismount the volume, which can damage your files, and applications will continue to display the contents of your docs even after the dismount, unless closed or otherwise touched. Be careful, as your fix may be more destructive than doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this utilizing the Windows **Task Scheduler**.

1. Begin by creating a new task. Switch to the **Triggers** tab and add a new trigger.
   You're going to want to trigger your task **On an event**.

   - Select the **System** log as the log in which the event will be logged.
   - Select **Kernel-Power** as the source of the event.
   - The Event ID will be **42**.

   [image]

   These setting correlate to an event as seen below in the **Event Viewer**:

   [image]
2. You're now going to want to add an action to your task. For that, you're going to want to invoke `TrueCrypt.exe` with the [`/dismount` command line argument](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/command-line-usage):

   [image]
3. Don't forget to name your task and set up any additional conditions you might need.

Please note, it might also be desirable to invoke the task when the workstation is locked. There is a more simple trigger for that. It's possible that the computer going to sleep will also trigger tasks that are set to run when the workstation is logged, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question ... this is what I've just set up to dismount my `M` drive:

1) A batch file that contains:

```
"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\truecrypt" /dismount m /q /f
```

2) Run the batch file from this [handy utility to run actions on Suspend and/or Resume](http://win7suspendresume.codeplex.com/).